# Plotting a rectangular area on the surface of a sphere

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, geopy

I am trying to trace out a rectangular area on the surface of a sphere.

This is the code I have for the sphere:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.set_aspect("equal")  

theta, phi =  np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi : 20j ,0:np.pi : 20j]

r = 6.3

x = r * np.cos(phi)*np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = r * np.cos(theta)

ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z, color = "k")
plt.show()
```

The points will be converted from lat/long to cart coords.

```
lat1x = 46.49913179 * (2*np.pi/360)
lat2x = 46.4423682 * (2*np.pi/360)
long1y = -119.4049072 * (2*np.pi/360)
long2y = -119.5048141 * (2*np.pi/360)

lat3x = 46.3973998 * (2*np.pi/360)
lat4x = 46.4532495 * (2*np.pi/360)
long3y = -119.4495392 * (2*np.pi/360)
long4y = -119.3492884 * (2*np.pi/360)


xw1 = r * np.cos(lat1x)*np.cos(long1y)
yw1 = r * np.cos(lat1x)*np.sin(long1y)
zw1 = r * np.sin(lat1x)

xw2 = r * np.cos(lat2x)*np.cos(long2y)
yw2 = r * np.cos(lat2x)*np.sin(long2y)
zw2 = r * np.sin(lat2x)

xw3 = r * np.cos(lat3x)*np.cos(long3y)
yw3 = r * np.cos(lat3x)*np.sin(long3y)
zw3 = r * np.sin(lat3x)

xw4 = r * np.cos(lat4x)*np.cos(long4y)
yw4 = r * np.cos(lat4x)*np.sin(long4y)
zw4 = r * np.sin(lat4x) 

p1 = [xw1,yw1,zw1]
p2 = [xw2,yw2,zw2]
p3 = [xw3,yw3,zw3]
p4 = [xw4,yw4,zw4]

ax.scatter(p1,p2,p3,p4, color = "r")
```

These are the points and there conversion to cartesian coordinates I am having trouble getting them to appear on the surface of the sphere. They should also form a rough rectangular shape. I would like to be able to connect the points to draw a rectangle on the surface of the sphere. As an aside the rectangle is meant to be very small

Comment: "I am trying" seems to be a euphemism. Have you acutally tried anything? What does "trace out" mean in this context? Which are the coordinates to plot? How would the expected plot look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion to cartesian coordinates may be wrong. Just like when creating the sphere, you might want to use the usual

[image]

But it will of course depend on how "lat" and "lon" are defined on the sphere.

More importantly, the scatter plot is incorrect. It's always `scatter(x,y,z)`, first argument x coordinates, second argument y coordinates, third argument z coordinates.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.set_aspect("equal")  

theta, phi =  np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi : 20j ,0:np.pi : 20j]

r = 6.3

x = r * np.cos(phi)*np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = r * np.cos(theta)

ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z, color = "k")


lat1x = 46.49913179 * (2*np.pi/360)
lat2x = 46.4423682 * (2*np.pi/360)
long1y = -119.4049072 * (2*np.pi/360)
long2y = -119.5048141 * (2*np.pi/360)

lat3x = 46.3973998 * (2*np.pi/360)
lat4x = 46.4532495 * (2*np.pi/360)
long3y = -119.4495392 * (2*np.pi/360)
long4y = -119.3492884 * (2*np.pi/360)

def to_cartesian(lat,lon):
    x = r * np.cos(lon)*np.sin(lat)
    y = r * np.sin(lon)*np.sin(lat)
    z = r * np.cos(lat)
    return [x,y,z]

p1 = to_cartesian(lat1x,long1y)
p2 = to_cartesian(lat2x,long2y)
p3 = to_cartesian(lat3x,long3y)
p4 = to_cartesian(lat4x,long4y)

X = np.array([p1,p2,p3,p4])
ax.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],X[:,2], color = "r")


plt.show()
```

Because the rectangle is pretty small you need to zoom in quite a bit in order to see it.

[image]